# Change tr background color based on conditionals thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am looking to change a table row's background color based on an th:if conditional.

For example: if expected != actual, bg = red. vice versa, bg = green.

For my example, I currently have three columns -- eval type, expected, and actual. The evaluation type determines the the values for expected and actual. The current span `th:style` highlights correctly the individual cells, but I am looking to have the entire `<tr>` highlighted red or green based on the evaluation.

Current code:

```
<thead> 
    <th>Eval Type </th>
    <th>Expected </th>
    <th>Actual </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
                    <span th:if="${example.getEvaluationType()} == '1'" th:text="${example.getExpectedcount()}" 
                    th:style="${example.getActualcount()} == ${example.getExpectedcount()} ? 'background: green' : 'background: red'"></span>

                    <span th:if="${example.getEvaluationType()} == '2'" th:text="${example.getExpectedmb()}"
                    th:style="${example.getActualmb()} == ${example.getExpectedmb()} ? 'background: green' : 'background: red'"></span>

                    <span th:if="${example.getEvaluationType()} == '3'" th:text="${example.getExpectedminutes()}" 
                    th:style="${example.getActualminutes()} == ${example.getExpectedminutes()} ? 'background: green' : 'background: red'" ></span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Appreciate any help or leads with related questions as I have not found any.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone curious:

I ended up taking the calculations being done above and doing them all in my backend `actual == expected ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'`. I assigned the output to a single variable `passed` .

Add the variable and correct get/setters to your program, and then this line will enable the output to color the entire row red / green.

`<tr th:style="${taskstatistics.getPassed()} == FALSE ? 'background: red' : 'background: green'">`

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behaviour (ie. changing the background of the cell, not the entire row) since you are using the span in a single `td`. Maybe you should consider moving your conditional styling to the `tr` (row tag) as the following code sample:

```
<tr th:style="${taskstatistics.getActual()} == ${taskstatistics.getExpected()} ? background-color: green' : 'background-color: red'">
```

Comment: Hey Ahmet - thank you for your comment. I changed the question to give more context, but I will try your solution by making a very long th:if statement haha. Thank you very much again!